# Append Multiple Sets of Cells to Bottom of Row

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, append

I've a spreadsheet that gets changed and added to that has one column of categories and multiple groups that have corresponding answers in two columns. These two columns are a "yes/no" column and the second a quantity.
[image]

I've been trying to take each group and place it below the next, to make a sheet that's easier to sort and filter where each category repeats down the first column followed by each group and their desired quantity.
[image]

I tried copying two sets of columns and looping through every other column. I couldn't get the categories to populate as well beside each entry.

Comment: Are there only that four (shown) categories. or they can be more? The same about the groups. Should they be 3, as in the shown picture, or they can be more?

Comment: Could be many more- this is just a sample I'm working with so I was using xl  on a given range

Comment: Can the "after" be on another sheet ?

Comment: That would be preferred actually

Comment: Then, test the code I posted. It should be very fast. But you received three answers and it would be good to test them, analyze and mark as accepted the one you like more. Not necessarily to be mine...

Comment: Thank you! I’ve been working through all three and each has their strengths. You’re right though yours runs quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub normalize()

   Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
   Dim j As Long, arCat, arData
   Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long
   Dim grp As String, r As Long, n As Long
   
   Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet3") ' before
   Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet4") ' after
   ws2.Range("A1:D1") = Array("Categories", "Group", "Want", "Quantity")
   
   With ws1
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        arCat = .Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Value2
        n = UBound(arCat)
        r = 2
        
        For j = 2 To lastcol Step 2
            grp = .Cells(1, j)
            arData = .Cells(2, j).Resize(n, 2)
            
            ws2.Cells(r, 1).Resize(n) = arCat
            ws2.Cells(r, 2).Resize(n) = grp
            ws2.Cells(r, 3).Resize(n, 2) = arData
            
            r = r + n
        Next
    End With
      
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Stack Groups of Data (Excel Formula)

```
=LET(Table,A1:M5,dCols,2,
    Data,DROP(Table,1),dRows,ROWS(Data),drSeq,SEQUENCE(dRows),
    hData,DROP(TAKE(Table,1),,1),hrSeq,SEQUENCE(dRows,,1,0),
    sData,TAKE(Data,,1),dData,DROP(Data,,1),
    rcSeq,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(dData)/dCols),
DROP(REDUCE("",rcSeq,LAMBDA(rRes,rc,LET(cc,dCols*rc-dCols+1,
    VSTACK(rRes,HSTACK(sData,INDEX(hData,hrSeq,cc),
        INDEX(dData,drSeq,SEQUENCE(,dCols,cc))))))),1))
```

[image]

### EDIT

- It's a lengthy formula and it is kind of clumsy to use it in your worksheet. Therefore you should create a lambda function out of it.
- Select `Ribbon->Formulas->Defined Names->Define Name` and in the `Name:` text box input a name e.g. `VStackGroups` and in the `Refers to:` text box enter the following formula:

```
=LAMBDA(Table,DataColumns,LET(
    Data,DROP(Table,1),dRows,ROWS(Data),drSeq,SEQUENCE(dRows),
    hData,DROP(TAKE(Table,1),,1),hrSeq,SEQUENCE(dRows,,1,0),
    sData,TAKE(Data,,1),dData,DROP(Data,,1),
    rcSeq,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(dData)/DataColumns),
DROP(REDUCE("",rcSeq,LAMBDA(rRes,rc,LET(cc,DataColumns*rc-DataColumns+1,
    VSTACK(rRes,HSTACK(sData,INDEX(hData,hrSeq,cc),
        INDEX(dData,drSeq,SEQUENCE(,DataColumns,cc))))))),1)))
```

- Now you can utilize the function e.g. with a simple

  ```
  =VStackGroups(A1:M5,2)
  ```

  and you could do it anywhere in the workbook with different data.

**Further More...**

- Sure, it is a cool formula. Unfortunately, you can't continue playing i.e. you can't *"filter and sort"* the data of a spilling formula.
- Therefore, after you have created the name, you could use some straightforward VBA to write the formula and convert it to values:

```vb
Sub StackGroups()
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_DATA_COLUMNS As Long = 2
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Sheet2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    
    Dim dfCell As Range
    
    With dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        ' Clear previous data.
        .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).ClearContents ' preserve headers
        ' Reference the first destination cell.
        Set dfCell = .Columns(1).Cells(2)
    End With
    
    ' Write formula.
    dfCell.Formula2 = "=VStackGroups('" & SRC_NAME & "'!" _
        & srg.Address & "," & SRC_DATA_COLUMNS & ")"
    
    ' Convert formula to values.
    With dws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' it's not the same as the previous one
        With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
    
End Sub
```

- To conclude, maybe (surely) going with just VBA is a better way in the first place. This was just to present alternatives and to show what you can achieve with the new Excel functions.

Comment: Thank you! I’ve not worked Lambda much so I’m learning a lot from your chosen method

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next way of processing. It should be very fast, even for larger ranges, using two arrays, all calculation being done in memory. The processing result is dropped at once at the end of the code. It drops the result in another sheet. Now, it returns in **the next sheet**, so, if you test it as it is take care to have an empty sheet after the active one (which to be processed):

```
Sub GroupCategories()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, lastcol As Long
 Dim arr, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set sh1 = sh.Next 'use here your sheet where to return. Now, it returns in the next sheet
 
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastcol = sh.cells(1, sh.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column

 arr = sh.Range("A1", sh.cells(lastR, lastcol)).Value2
 ReDim arrFin(1 To (UBound(arr) - 1) * (lastcol - 1) / 2 + 1, 1 To 4)

 'fill the header in the array:
 arrFin(1, 1) = "Categories": arrFin(1, 2) = "Group": arrFin(1, 3) = "Want": arrFin(1, 4) = "Quantity"
 k = 2 'initialixe the variable keeping the array row
 
 For i = 2 To UBound(arr, 2) Step 2
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
        arrFin(k, 1) = arr(j + 1, 1): arrFin(k, 2) = arr(1, i)
        arrFin(k, 3) = arr(j + 1, i): arrFin(k, 4) = arr(j + 1, i + 1)
        k = k + 1
    Next j
 Next i
 
 'drop the procesed array result at once and format a little:
 With sh1.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 4)
    .Value2 = arrFin
    .rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
 End With
 
 MsgBox "Ready...": sh1.Activate
End Sub
```